# How to quit R script when an error occurred

Tags: r, bash

I am writing an R script as a command to run in terminal, and I found if an error happen when running this script, the command still returns a normal exit signal. So I cannot check the running results by checking `[ $? -ne 0 ]`, it just returns `succeed`.

[image]

[image]

This is because R will continue running the next command when it encounters an error in previous command. Is there any way to solve this situation?

Best,

Shixiang

Comment: Wrap the script in a function and call the function at the end of the script?

Comment: @Roland They key point is letting the R quit with a signature not equal to 0, see my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I combine `tryCatch()` and `quit()` to solve this problem. I firstly wrap my main function to `tryCatch` structure to let it detect if an error occurred, once an error is detected, I print the error message and call `quit("no", -1)` to quit R with exit status signature `-1`.

[image]